# Prolog Predicate Solution

Tags: list, prolog

I am going through some past exam questions for my prolog exam that is coming up.

Here is the question:

2. (a) Write a predicate `insert(Xs, Y, Zs)` that holds when `Zs` is the list obtained
   by inserting `Y` into the list `Xs`. A query such as:

   ```
   ? - insert([1,2,3], 4, Zs).
   ```

should succeed four times and give the following answers:

```
Zs = [4, 1, 2, 3]

Zs = [1, 4, 2, 3]

Zs = [1, 2, 4, 3]

Zs = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

I'm a bit concerned because I have no idea where to start. Would anyone be able to help out as I need example solutions to practice for my exam.

Would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `insert(Xs, Y, Zs)` should *define what it looks like when `Zs` is the list `Xs` with `Y` inserted somewhere*. To define the rule, you break it into logical cases. Your main definition will be recursive. But a simple base case is that `Z` just looks like `Xs` with `Y` as its first element (`[Y|Xs]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that one answer that the question might be looking for goes along these lines:

```
insert(List, Element, NewList) :-
    append(Front, Back, List), % split list in two
    append(Front, [Element|Back], NewList). % reassemble list
```

If you would like a declarative reading:

> NewList has Element between the front and the back of List.

Check carefully if `append/3` or a predicate with the same semantics appears in the earlier questions or the study material.

And note that this is in essence the exact same solution as the [suggestion by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36621270/1812457), if I understand it correctly. Consult the textbook definition of `append/3` for details. Or even better, look at the textbook definition of `append/3` and adapt it to use if for "inserting".

Answer (score 3):

We start by changing the terrible name of this predicate: The predicate should describe **what holds**, *not* what to do. The name should reflect that. I suggest `list_with_element/3`, and encourage you to try finding even better names, ideally making clear what **each** argument stands for.

Then, we do what we set out to do: Describe the cases that make this relation hold.

For example:

```
list_with_element([], E, [E]).
list_with_element([L|Ls], E, [E,L|Ls]).
list_with_element([L|Ls0], E, [L|Ls]) :-
        ...
```

I leave filling in the `...` as an easy exercise. State the condition that is necessary for the clause head to be true!

**EDIT**: I would like to say a bit more about the pattern above. In my experience, a good way—and definitely in the beginning—to reason about predicates that describe *lists* is to consider two basic cases:

1. the atom `[]`, denoting the empty list
2. terms of the form `'.'(E, Es)`, also written as `[E|Es]`, where `E` is the first element of the list and `Es` is again a list.

This follows the inductive definition of lists.

The drawback in this specific case is that this approach leads to a situation where case (2) again needs to be divided into two subcases, and somehow unexpectedly necessitates *three* clauses to handle the *two* basic cases. This obviously runs counter to our intuitive expectation that *two* clauses should suffice. Indeed they do, but we need to be careful not to accidentally lose solutions. In this case, the first two clauses above are *both* subsumed by the fact:

```
list_with_element(Ls, E, [E|Ls]).
```

Every experienced Prolog coder will write such predicates in this way, or just, as in this case, use `select/3` directly. This is what @lurker sensed and hinted at, and @tas correctly shows that a different clause (which is easy to come up with accidentally) does *not* fully subsume all cases we want to express.

Thus, I still find it a lot easier to think first about the empty list explicitly, make sure to get that case correct, then continue with more complex cases, and then see if you can write the existing program more compactly. This is the way I also used for this sample code, but I did not make it as short as possible. Note that with monotonic code, it is completely OK to have redundant facts!

Note that is is specifically **not** OK to just replace the first two clauses by:

```
list_with_element([L|Ls], E, [E|Ls]).
```

because this clause does not subsume case (1) above.

Comment: @mat thanks for the help - could you please post up the full solution just so I can check my predicate? .. thanks.

Comment: @lurker: The first rule only matches the empty list as first argument. The second rule only matches lists with at least one element as first argument. In `list_with_element([L|Ls], E, [E|Ls]).` the third argument is *not* the first argument + element `E` but only the tail of the first list + `E`.

Comment: @tas yep I'm award of that. My question is why those two rules couldn't be replaced with the one I suggested.

Comment: @lurker: If I insert the, as it seems to me, one obvious recursive goal in the suggested solution of @mat and run the above query I get the expected solutions from above. If I comment out the first rule I get only: `[4,1,2,3], [1,4,2,3], [1,2,4,3]`. If I replace  the first two rules by the one in your comment I get: `[4,2,3], [1,4,3], [1,2,4]`. So the first rule of @mat is needed to get all 4 solutions. Your suggested first rule is *replacing* one element. That is of course, if we have the same body for the recursive rule in mind. I was thinking `list_with_element(Ls0,E,Ls).` ;-)

Comment: @tas sorry I had an error in my suggested rule. It should have read `list_with_element(L, E, [E|L]).` Try that instead of mat's first two rules.

Comment: @mat sorry I had an error in my comment (it didn't match what I had actually played with). See my latest comment. I believe it covers rules (1) and (2), but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @User15388472 why don't you run tests on your predicate to see if it works? If you get an error and don't understand it, you can post a specific question on that error.

Comment: @lurker: You are right, that subsumes the first 2 rules. Silly me, I didn't think about that. Very elegant :-)

Comment: @mat thanks for your edits relative to the alternatives discussed in the comments. I think they are very elucidating.

Comment: First, as I already said, I recommend you pick a better name for this predicate, so that it makes sense to read it in all directions. Further, you only have to add a *single goal* to the version I showed to complete the definition. Think declaratively: The head reads: `list_with_element([L|Ls0], E, [L|Ls]) :-`. **When** does this hold? What must hold about `L`, `Ls0`, `E` and `Ls` so that we can say: "Yes, `[L|Ls]` is just like the list `[L|Ls0]` except that `E` also definitely occurs somewhere in `Ls`."? Think about it, express it as a Prolog goal, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in predicate [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) that does the same thing, although with the arguments in a different order.

Remember that (if defined correctly) a predicate can work in different directions. For instance, it can tell you what a list would look like after removing an element, it can (although it's fairly trivial) tell you what element to remove from one list to get another, or it can tell you *what lists, after having a given element removed, would resemble a given list.*
<sub>(Hint: you may want to look into that last one).</sub>